# How to pay zakat in non-fasting days as a woman?

Tags: ramadan, zakat

As a woman, I get my period for one week. In that week during ramadan, I don't fast. In these non-fasting days, I must give zakat to the poor. What kind of zakat do I give? How much zakat should I give for each non-fasting day? I am a woman that does not have a job yet but has some savings.

Comment: Zakat does not have anything to do with fasting, unless you are talking about  Sadaqat-ul-Fitr. You do not need to pay any charity for fasts that you miss because of periods, you just have to make up for missed days later.

Comment: Why you need to give zakat while you don't fast? Giving zakat to non-Muslims is hardly allowed.

Comment: There's some rule in Islam that says that when a person doesn't fast because they are sick or breaks his fast for any reason has to feed 60 people or pay an amount. Not entirely sure about the certainty of this, perhaps you can help me understand it.

Comment: There should be some posts covering the topic of kaffarah. Therefore I think it is better to clear your confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing Zakat with Kaffara and Fidyah.  Kaffara is due on a person who **breaks** their fast **without** a valid excuse, it is not due on those who have an excuse to not fast, such as a sick person or a traveler, they only have to do قضاء

> فمن شهد منكم الشهر فليصمه ومن كان مريضا أو على سفر فعدة من أيام أخر
>
> So whoever sights [the new moon of] the month, let him fast it; and whoever is ill or on a journey - then an equal number of other days.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:185](http://quran.com/2/185)</sup>

Similarly, a menstruating woman is not required to pay it. Rather she needs to fast additional days to make up for those that she missed.

> كان يصيبنا ذلك فنؤمر بقضاء الصوم ولا نؤمر بقضاء الصلاة
>
> That used to happen to us and we were commanded to make up the fasts but we were not commanded to make up the prayers
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/3/85) and [Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai/22/229)</sup>